# Perl pattern matching from one file and write to another file

Tags: perl

I have a text file like below:

```
1.temp _result runCount = 0
start testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
Resetting Statistics ...
end   testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001
time  testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001 elapsed 46.968
PASS  testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001 
start testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_001
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
Resetting Statistics ...
end   testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_001
FAIL testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_001 targetCosq::CosqSchedConfig (0, 3, 7, sched_mode=WRR, sched_weight=1) expected PASS but was     bcm_cosq_gport_sched_set(0, 3, 7, 3, 1) expected 0 but was -9..
start testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_002
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
XXXetcXXX
Resetting Statistics ...
end   testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_002
time  testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_002 elapsed 100.078
PASS  testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_002
```

I need to print as:

```
Count TestCase                          Verdit

1     testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001              PASS

2     testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_001             FAIL

3     testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_002             PASS
```

Could anyone suggest some tips on how to do this?

Comment: Please show what you've tried with a code sample.

Comment: Is the 'count' actual a sequence number for the test? Can any of the 'XXXetcXXX' lines ever look like 'PASS testcase::name'? Is the name `testCaseCosqSched` fixed, or could it be any string? It really looks rather trivial; Perl can certainly do the job, but so could `awk` with ease.

Comment: Hi Janathon thanks for the responce. My test case start at start testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001
 and than ends at the Resetting Statistics ...
end . but for the pass test case it show the time first and than the verdit followd by testcsae name. but for the fail test case it dose not show the time diretly verdit fail followed by testcse name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'printf "%-5d  %-70s  %s\n", ++$i, $2, $1 if m/^(PASS|FAIL)\s+(\S+)/' data
```

Since the test names are over 60 characters long, you need that much space allocated for them.

Output:

```
1      testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_mixed_001            PASS
2      testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_001           FAIL
3      testCaseCosqSched::testCosqSched_ext_lossless_sched_update_002           PASS
```

Not exactly Perl rocket science.